# How to count rows before while()

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, count, rows

I need to count rows before while().

On page there are 10 questions. 5 questions on left, 5 questions on right.

It looks like this:

```
<div class="left"> 

<div>question 1</div>
<div>question 2</div>
<div>question 3</div>
<div>question 4</div>
<div>question 5</div>
</div> <!-- /left close --> 

<div class="right"> 

<div>question 6</div>
<div>question 7</div>
<div>question 8</div>
<div>question 9</div>
<div>question 10</div>
</div> <!-- /right close -->
```

Data getting from mysql.

Comment: if 1 2 3 4 or 5 should be on left, else on the right side.  two columns

Comment: where is your `while`?

Comment: *Question Is Unclear*

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: It's `(int)($number_of_questions / $number_of_columns)`. For your case `10 / 2 = 5`.

Comment: Put *limit* in query.

Comment: <div class="left"> then goes while().. ten data from table. but after 5 rows then should be div class right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this sample:

```
<?php 
 $dir = 'left';
 $count = 0;
 foreach($data as $row):
   $count++;
   if($count%5==1):
   ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $dir?>"> 
    <?php
     $dir = 'right';
   endif;
   ?>
    <div>question <?php echo $count?></div>
   <?php
   if($count%5==0 || $count == sizeof($data)):
   ?>
      </div> 
   <?php
   endif;
 endforeach;
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks that worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is Unclear but from your question title- you can get number of rows before while loop with  `mysql_num_rows ($result )` see full doc here  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using PDO, if the rows are from the db, then you could do something like this after executing your statement:

```
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
```

and use the `$count` for your while loop like this:

```
<?php
    $question_number    =   1;
    $while($question_number <= $count){

    //Your code goes here:

    $question_number++;
    }
?>
```

I hope this helps.